# How can I use Webfont Loader with Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to use [Webfont Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) to manage the loading of a custom font and also to load a couple Google fonts. However, I'm not sure how to integrate it with Gatsby. I found a [React wrapper for Webfont Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dr-kobros/react-webfont-loader), but it wants you to use it like this:

```
<WebfontLoader config={config} onStatus={callback}>
  <App />
</WebfontLoader>
```

which doesn't seem to me to be compatible with Gatsby. Is there a way to adapt it so it will work with Gatbsy? Or a way to adapt the [unwrapped npm webfontloader module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfontloader) to work with Gatsby?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at how these guys did it here: https://github.com/smartive/smartive.ch/blob/master/src/layouts/index.js

That example is still a little above my knowledge so I tried a simpler way and it works just fine for me (though might not be the "cleanest" approach etc)

in my layouts/index.js I import:

```
import './main.js'
```

in which I have the following:

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {

window.onload=function(){

  var WebFont = require('webfontloader');

  WebFont = {
      typekit: { id: 'psj0mst' }
   };

   (function(d) {
      var wf = d.createElement('script'), s = d.scripts[0];
      wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js';
      wf.async = true;
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
   })(document);

}
}
```

I had to add the check for window because otherwise I got an error when building the gatsby site for production.

Comment: Cheers for finding that solution, and also for rigging up a solution that works for you. It seems like this needs to be more completely addressed by the Gatsby team.

Comment: If you share your code, I'll try to help get the more Reacty version working for you.

Comment: I've been using the above solution which involves using `componentDidMount` on the Index page, but that's too late in the page loading process. I think I'll go back to loading the fonts in `html.js` for now.

Comment: `componentDidMount()` is not called during the initial build for server-side-rendering, since the component is never mounted. Including the JavaScript in a <script> tag inside the render function is probably the way to go. Helmet makes this easy.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [gatsby plugin](https://github.com/escaladesports/gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader#readme) to do this work:

Install

```
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader
```

And Use

```
    plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader',
      options: {
        google: {
          families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```